# Deja-dup broken package is blocking any apt operation

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deja-dup

After reinstalling gnome, deja-dup seemed to be installed not correctly. So when i use any operation of apt i get the following error:
`E: The package deja-dup needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

I tried to configure it with dpkg, but got an error messgae:
`package deja-dup is not ready for configuration. Cannot configure (current status 'half installed')`

Any idea how i can solve? Knowing that i only can access tty(due to another problem with gpu).
And here's the output of `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.anydesk.com all InRelease
Get:3 https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease [2 456 B]
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Get:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease [57,7 kB]
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease
Hit:9 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tomtomtom/woeusb/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:11 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:12 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:13 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:14 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-proposed InRelease
Fetched 60,1 kB in 4s (15,2 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
```

Output of `grep -ir ^deb /etc/apt --include="*.list"`:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-proposed multiverse universe main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teamviewer.list:deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teams.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list:deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/tomtomtom-ubuntu-woeusb-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tomtomtom/woeusb/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mendeleydesktop.list:deb https://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable main
```

output of `apt-cache policy deja-dup`

```
deja-dup:
  Installed: 40.7-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 40.7-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 40.7-0ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     40.6-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: which ubuntu release? `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get update` and add full output to the question.

Comment: @nobody I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: @N0rbert I've added it now)

Comment: Also please add `grep -ir ^deb /etc/apt --include="*.list"` and `apt-cache policy deja-dup` .

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: deja-dup is in focal-updates main.  Maybe the version is removed from your mirror you use, can you try another one?